# Audio file is not playing in java

Tags: java, audio, media-player

I'm trying to play an audio file using MediaPlayer but it's not working and showing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! uri == 'audio.mp3'
```

Can anyone help me to fix this ?

Here is my code:

```
package playaudio;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class PlayAudio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "audio.mp3";
        Media playFile = new Media(fileName);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(playFile);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

}
```

EDIT: When i try converting the filename to a URI it shows following exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized
```

Code:

```
package playaudio;

import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class PlayAudio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fileName = "audio.mp3";
        Media playFile = new Media(Paths.get(fileName).toUri().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(playFile);
        mediaPlayer.play();
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null! " error using JavaFX to play audio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028044/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-uri-getscheme-null-error-using-jav)

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem. i tried that but shows exception. :/

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `Media` actually requires a URI, meaning that you will have to convert the filename to a URI, try this:

`Media media = new Media(Paths.get(fileName).toUri().toString());`

Comment: I tried that, but still shows-       

      Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized

Comment: [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896798/javafx-media-player-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("audio.wav");
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);     
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
```

But, this will only work for .wav files.